# How to move text to bottom of JButton

Tags: java, swing, layout, icons, jbutton

I have a JButton created using the following code.

```
JButton button = new JButton ( "Document",appletRec.getIcon()) ;
button.addActionListener ( this ) ;                    
button.setOpaque                 ( true ) ; //changed false from true.
button.setFocusPainted           ( true ) ; //changed false from true.
button.actAsLink                 ( true ) ;
button.setHighlightForeground    ( Color.blue ) ;
button.setVerticalTextPosition   ( SwingConstants.BOTTOM ) ;
button.setVerticalAlignment      ( SwingConstants.TOP ) ;
button.setHorizontalTextPosition ( SwingConstants.CENTER ) ;
```

But my button is appearing like this 
[image]

I want to move the text to the bottom of the button. Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: "changed false from true" doesn't tell the future code maintainer *why* the change was made. Comments should strive to tell people why changes were made, not what was changed.

Comment: Hi Dave, I added this comment for myself for today testing. I will change it, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[button.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setVerticalAlignment%28int%29)  will move everything (**text + icon**) to the bottom of the button.

If you want spacing between the text and the icon, you can use 
[button.setIconTextGap(int distance)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIconTextGap%28int%29)

Answer (score 4):

If you change

```
button.setVerticalAlignment ( SwingConstants.TOP ) ;
```

to

```
button.setVerticalAlignment ( SwingConstants.BOTTOM ) ;
```

the label will be displayed in the bottom of your button.